# Is there a common standard for denoting sets of particular relations/functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, notation, relations, universal-algebra

I know that the set of functions $X\to Y$ can be denoted $Y^X$ (using cardianl exponentiation), and I've seen cardinal factorials used for the set of bijections from a set to itself. Personally, I've also used $\text{Bi}(X,Y)$, $\text{In}(X,Y)$, and $\text{Sur}(X,Y)$ to denote the set of bijections, injections, and surjections, respectively, and I've generally done the same with other types of functions (ex. $\text{Iso}(X,Y)$ for isomorphism, etc).

Well today, I was working on a problem involving "the set of all well-orders on a given set," "the set of binary operations on a well-orderd set," and "the set of homomorphisms between magmas over the same." While I was doing this, I couldn't help but think "it would be awfully handy if there were a standard way to abbreviate all these sets!"

So, how about it? Is there a standard for denoting specific sets of relations/functions on a set (ex. total-orders, equivalence relations, group operations)? Perhaps an index of commonly used notations?

---

Note: I am referring to functions/relations over a *given* set, rather than in general. I've seen notations for "the class/category of < structure >" (ex. **Ord** - category of preordered sets, $\mathfrak{G}$ - class of groups), but I'm not aware of these being used to refer to structures over a specific set (e.g. $\textbf{Ord}(X)$ for the set of preorders on $X$). I bring this up because, in most cases, "the set of relations/functions on $X$ such that $Y$" can be identified with the set of structures over $X$ that satisfy $Y$ (for example, the set of rings whose underlying set is $X$).

Comment: Set Theory uses $[Y]^k$ for the set of subsets of $Y$ of cardinal $k,$ for finite or infinite cardinal $k$. E.g. $[Y]^2=\{\{s,t\}: s,t\in Y\land s\ne t\}.$ Also, similarly,  $[Y]^{\le k}$ and $[Y]^{<k}.$ Also $Fn(A,B,k),$ defined as $\{f: C\to B \;|\;C\in [A]^{<k}\},$ which occurs a lot in Forcing.When $k=\aleph_0$ (or the cardinal ordinal $ \omega),$ $Fn(A,B,\omega)$ is sometimes abbreviated to $Fn(A,B)$ and is called the set of finite partial functions from $A$ to $B. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That said, I've never seen the "$Fn$" notations used that way *outside* forcing, and in a non-forcing paper I'd assume "$Fn(A,B)$" was an odd way of referring to $B^A$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber . Outside of books, papers, presentations, and lectures,   on Forcing, I don't think I've seen $Fn$ anywhere else either.